# rvm install fails searching for binary rubies on a vagrant box

Tags: ruby, rvm, vagrant

I am trying to install rvm on a vagrant box Ubuntu 12.04. When I run the vagrant script the installation halts due to an error with this command:

```
curl -L https://get.rvm.io | sudo bash -s stable --ruby=$RUBY_VER --auto-dotfiles --verify-downloads 1
```

This is the output of that command running inside the vagrant script:

```
Turning on auto dotfiles mode.
Please read and follow further instructions.
Press ENTER to continue.
Downloading RVM from wayneeseguin branch stable

Upgrading the RVM installation in /usr/local/rvm/
source /etc/profile.d/rvm.sh
Upgrade of RVM in /usr/local/rvm/ is complete.

Upgrade Notes:

  * No new notes to display.

# In case of problems:
#        run and read: rvm notes
#           read docs: http://rvm.io/
#          talk to us: http://webchat.freenode.net/?channels=rvm
#     read cheatsheet: http://cheat.errtheblog.com/s/rvm
#    watch screencast: http://screencasts.org/episodes/how-to-use-rvm
#   open a bug report: https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/issues

# vagrant,
#
#   Thank you for using RVM!
#   I sincerely hope that RVM helps to make your life easier and more enjoyable!
!!
#
# ~Wayne

rvm 1.21.6 (stable) by Wayne E. Seguin <wayneeseguin@gmail.com>, Michal Papis <m
papis@gmail.com> [https://rvm.io/]

Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
.o binary rubies available for: ubuntu/12.04/i386/ruby-1.9.3-p374
Continuing with compilation. Please read 'rvm help mount' to get more informatio
n on binary rubies.
Installing requirements for ubuntu, might require sudo password.
Requirements installation successful.
, this may take a while depending on your cpu(s)...es/ruby-1.9.3-p374
, this may take a while depending on your connection...
.tar.bz2', it's not possible to validate it.ng.org/pub/ruby/1.9/ruby-1.9.3-p374
This could be because your RVM install's list of versions is out of date. You ma
y want to
update your list of rubies by running 'rvm get stable' and try again.
If that does not resolve the issue and you wish to continue with unverified down
load
add '--verify-downloads 1' after the command.

There has been an error fetching the ruby interpreter. Halting the installation.
```

However when I try to run the same instruction on the command line of the vagrant box it seems to work:

```
vagrant@precise32:~$ curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | sudo bash -s stable --ruby=1.9.3-p374 --auto-dotfiles --verify-downloads 1
```

The output is this:

```
Turning on auto dotfiles mode.
Please read and follow further instructions.
Press ENTER to continue.
Downloading RVM from wayneeseguin branch stable

Upgrading the RVM installation in /usr/local/rvm/

Upgrade of RVM in /usr/local/rvm/ is complete.

Upgrade Notes:

  * No new notes to display.

# In case of problems:
#        run and read: rvm notes
#           read docs: http://rvm.io/
#          talk to us: http://webchat.freenode.net/?channels=rvm
#     read cheatsheet: http://cheat.errtheblog.com/s/rvm
#    watch screencast: http://screencasts.org/episodes/how-to-use-rvm
#   open a bug report: https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/issues

# vagrant,
#
#   Thank you for using RVM!
#   I sincerely hope that RVM helps to make your life easier and more enjoyable!!!
#
# ~Wayne


rvm 1.21.6 (stable) by Wayne E. Seguin <wayneeseguin@gmail.com>, Michal Papis <mpapis@gmail.com> [https://rvm.io/]

Already installed ruby-1.9.3-p374.
To reinstall use:

    rvm reinstall 1.9.3-p374

Creating alias default for ruby-1.9.3-p374.
Recording alias default for ruby-1.9.3-p374.
Creating default links/files
Saving wrappers to '/usr/local/rvm/bin'........

  * To start using RVM you need to run `source /usr/local/rvm/scripts/rvm`
    in all your open shell windows, in rare cases you need to reopen all shell windows.
```

Any ideas? I guess I could run manually the instructions on the vagrant files one by one but it would ruin the entire purpose of using provisioning. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is not a question, it's a bug report, it should be opened here: https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/issues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind. It happened that my Git was configured to convert line ending from Linux to Windows format automatically, so when I downloaded the vagrant files they turned useless when Linux tried to extract Ruby version (and other stuff like that) from them.

So the solution in my case was to reinstall Git, setting "Configuring the line ending conversions" to "Checkout as-is, commit as-is":

[image: Intallation of Git with not line ending conversion]